# Calling another method in parent class by using self.parent sometimes failed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have 1 `CCScene` (`PlayScene`) with 2 `CCLayer` (`PlayLayer` and `HUDLayer`) as its children. In my `PlayLayer.m` I'm calling another method which I've declared in `PlayScene` class. The way I call the method is by this code (in `PlayLayer.m`):

```
[(PlayScene *) self.parent gameStory:@"story2.png"];
```

The method is declared like this (in `PlayScene.h`):

```
-(void)gameStory:(NSString *)imgName;
```

The thing that puzzled me is, I've done the same way like this in the bottom of my code, and it works, the method gets called. But when I tried to have another calling of this method, way earlier at the beginning of the PlayLayer.m, then it's failed due to the `self.parent = (null)`.

Can anyone help me shed some lights please?

P.S That method will eventually call another method in `HUDLayer.m`, just in case this is matter to make it clearer to you.

Comment: Are you sure that self.parent was set correctly at the time when "early" call happens?

Comment: you can access a parant method in a child class directly!!
like '[self gameStory:@"image.png"]';
and what is the 'parent' object ..? maybe i don't get ur question

Comment: To put '(PlayScene *)' when calling self.parent is actually to avoid the warning message by xcode, something like typecast.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use delegates to call parent method:
http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html

http://obj-c.pl/objective-c-podstawy-1-3-klasy-i-delegaty/

Comment: I think delegate is a good option, to make it more neat. Will try it out, rather than stuck in there too long. But is it worth to have protocol like that while it's only being used by 1 class (in my case)?

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize a child node, its parent property will be nil during initialization.

Solution: defer code that needs access to the parent to onEnter, which is called when addChild is run:

```
-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        // does not work, parent is nil:
        [(PlayScene *) self.parent gameStory:@"story2.png"];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];

    // works, parent is set:
    [(PlayScene *) self.parent gameStory:@"story2.png"];
}
```